# Build failed after update coroutines to 1.2.0: META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

After update to `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.0` android build failed with issue:
`More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'`

Are there any workaround to make it work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In app-level `build.gradle` add the following to `android` level :-

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst("META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module")
}
```

It would look like :-

```
android {
  .......

  packagingOptions {
    ......
    pickFirst("META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module")
  }
}
```

Comment: On kotlin slack channel `exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'` also has been suggested. With proguard setting `-dontwarn kotlinx.atomicfu.**`

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-dontwarn kotlinx.atomicfu.**` to my proguard rules file was enough to get my build working with version `1.2.1` of the `kotlinx-coroutines-android` library.

Adding the `packagingOptions { pickFirst('META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module') }` or `packagingOptions { exclude('META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module') }` block in my `build.gradle` file didn't work.